# Block IP range with PF in Yosemite

Tags: macos, firewall, osx-yosemite

I want to limit the internet access for one of my apps installed on my mac (Yosemite).
I tried many utilities including TCPBlock, but none of them is working... I know that Yosemite is using PF as build-in firewall, so I want to try this also, but I can't find any help regarding the terminal commands. So my question is:

How can I block IP ranges (outbound connection) for one custom app? If it's not possible for one specific app, then it's okay if the rule is for every app on the mac.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You can block IP ranges using Little Snitch.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Isn't there a FREE solution?